# Questions about RS422 driver

Tags: ttl, rs422

I am using a GPS receiver board which transmits a PPS signal into a TTL <-> RS422 board I need to design.

**The receiving end (of the RS422 signal) is 15-20 meters away.**

Here is my design:

[image: TTL - RS422 Converter]

My questions are:

1. I've been asked by the manufacturer of the receiving end to put a 500 Ohm resistor between The high and low signals. **They do not have termination at their end.** On the other hand, an experienced engineer told me I need to place two resistors in series with the high and low signals.

So, with the receiving device being not so far away, and having no termination at all, and my signal being very very slow (unless the name is completely misleading, I assume one pulse per second is 1Hz), do I even need resistors? If so, what value?

I thought about putting three 0 Ohm resistors in my design (two in series, one in parallel) that can be later be swapped if this doesn't work. Thoughts?

2. On the datasheet of the LTC2850 it is said:

> If a high 
>   driver 
>   output 
>   is    shorted 
>   to 
>   a voltage 
>   just 
>   above
>   V
>   CC
>   ,  a  reverse 
>   current 
>   will 
>   flow 
>   into 
>   the 
>   supply. 
>   When
>   this 
>   voltage 
>   exceeds 
>   V
>   CC
>     by 
>   about  1.4V
>   ,  the 
>   reverse
>   current 
>   turns 
>   off 
>   ....
>   The
>    worst
>   -case
>    peak
>    reverse
>    short
>   -circuit
>    current
>    can
>    be as 
>   high 
>   as 300mA 
>   in    extreme 
>   cold 
>   conditions. 
>   If   this 
>   current 
>   can 
>   not 
>   be 
>   absorbed 
>   by 
>   the 
>   supply, 
>   a 3.6V 
>   Zener 
>   diode 
>   can 
>   be added in parallel with the supply to sink this current.

So, a few points about this:

- this is a very small board and what I showed you is the whole board.
  There are no other voltages.
- This device does operate in extreme cold conditions.
- the power supply board is not of my own design and I
  don't really know how it operates.

So, do I really need a zener diode?

3. This is based on an older deisgn (which used MAX13081E). I needed to switch to the LTC2850 due to having a supply of 33V instead of 5V like in the MAX13081E.
   In the older design, there was a 4.7uF electrolytic capacitor in addition to the 0.1uF bypass capacitor. Is there any reason why I need to place this capacitor?
4. This is the function table from the datasheet:
   [image: LTC2850 Function Table]

I only need to receive a PPS signal and transmit it in RS422. I assume the last state is what I'm looking for?

5. The resistors in the enable pins. There are two reasons why they are there:

   - To conserve current consumption
   - So it will be easier to change the function of the device by soldering them to ground if needed. Or just disconnecting them altogether, though I don't think it's a wise thing to do.

So my questions about them are - is it okay to have them at a 10k value (is it not too big or too small that it actually changes the state of the device), or in other words, how do I calculate their desired value in such a way that I have the minimum current consumption **and** the state of the device is what I intended it to be?

6. Last - is there a way to simulate this in LTSpice? Can standards like RS422 be simulated?

Thank you!

Comment: RS422 IS NOT a protocol.

Comment: it's a standard, right?

Comment: It's a standard but it isn't a protocol. The protocol is how you apply ones and zeros to the device and framing and CRC stuff etc..

Comment: I really need answers on my other questions, please. Especially the zener question (2), the 4.7uF capacitor (3) and if you can, the LTSpice question (6). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question, but it has not been answered correctly.  None of the comments answer it correctly either.

To define what is important, the pulse rate is not significant.  This is a timing signal from a GPS receiver.  The time of the edge of the 1 PPM signal is important.  To maintain that as accurately as possible, the edge shape needs to be preserved.  Even more importantly, the shape of the edge should preclude adverse effect from noise at the point of threshold crossing.  So it needs to be as fast as practical.

To achieve this goal, the driver, line and receiver impedance, all need to be matched.  The receiver has no terminator in the box, but this can be added at the connector end of the cable.  That value should match the impedance of the line.  The output impedance of the driver should also match the impedance of the line.  A common value used with RS-422 circuits is 100 ohms, often rounded up to 110 ohms.  The outputs should have 50 or 55 ohm resistors in series.  Then, a 100 ohm cable will present a differential signal of 2.4Vpp minimum, and the receiver will see a clean edge, with no reflection.

If impedance matching is not done, the arriving edge can reflect back, and reflect again from the driver, resulting in non-monotonic rising and falling edges.  A 40 meter round trip is approximately 120 ns, far enough that measures need to be taken to prevent these reflections.

What is important is not the rate of the pulse, but the required rise and fall times of the signal.

Comment: Regarding edge rate and termination, one can also rightfully ask whether the 20Mbps version transmitter is required; if the edge rate is consistent, it can be acceptable without loss of timing accuracy. I'm not sure offhand how consistent RS-422 transmitters are, so staying on the faster side is probably justified.

Comment: Yes, the edge rate itself is likely not crucial if it is consistent.  But both edge rates and thresholds vary with PVT (Process, Voltage and Temperature).  Even with a consistent edge rate, the timing of the 1 pps signal is absolute, not relative, so all errors can be significant.  My main concern would be the quality of the edges creating double threshold crossings.  But, maybe I'm being overly cautious.  I saw a lot of poor advice about terminations and wanted to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should post separate questions.

I will answer the first one - when termination is not necessary?

If the signal is very slow (1 pulse per second definitely is), then you do not need termination.

See for example [this post from TI](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/analogwire/archive/2016/07/28/rs-485-basics-when-termination-is-necessary-and-how-to-do-it-properly):

> One situation in which you don’t need termination networks is when the two-way loop time of the network is much greater than a single bit time (~<0.1×two-way loop delay). In such scenarios, the reflections will lose energy each time they reach an end of the network.

Comment: I don't understand the TI post. The reflections will lost energy - is that a good thing? I mean, you don't want reflections... right?

Comment: The driver pumped a pulse into a transmission line. The energy is "gone". It is now running down the line. Some will be absorbed by the receiver. The rest can either be absorbed by termination at the receiving end or bounce back. In both cases the driver does not care. You use termination, because you don't want the reflection to coincide with your data (how the receiver is supposed to know if it is data or a reflection?).

Comment: Not exactly true. If the rising/falling edges of the signal are too fast, the reflections can interfere with the signal’s zero crossings causing “bounces” Resistors in series is one way to slow down the edges enough to remove those reflections. .

Comment: @EdgarBrown but in my case, are the resistors needed? If there are resistors, will they pose a problem?

Comment: Add a place for a terminating resistor on the PCB. You don't have to mount it. When the device is ready just measure the lines with a scope and see how the signals look with and without the terminator.

Comment: @filo That's what I thought to do. I am wondering about the resistors in series an experienced engineer told to place. Don't know if they should be placed or not.

Comment: Add a couple of ~30ohm resistors in series with the outputs. That does two things: (1) it slows the signal edges thus reducing the need for line termination, and (2) together with the ~20ohm impedance of the drivers these create source termination thus quenching any reflections from the far end. That’s all that you would need.

Comment: @EdgarBrown Thank you very much! I will add those resistors. I'm just wondering, is it really necessary for the signal edges to be slowed if the signal itself is so slow to begin with? Reminding you, this is 1 pulse per second.

Comment: @Eran it depends on the other elements in the signal chain. If the signal edges are too fast, an unterminated line will have multiple zero crossings in each edge. If the signal chain somehow filters or ignores  all these zero crossings then it is not an issue, if it doesn’t, you now detect multiple erroneous pulses. It costs next to nothing to avoid them altogether. Source termination, contrary to end termination, does not consume any extra power.

Comment: @Eran the other solution is to simply use slower transceivers more commensurate with the signal’s speed. But you are using 20Mb/s ones. That means you will have signal components in the order of 100Mhz.